# svelte: how can I declare two cyclically reactive variables?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit

I have two variables `a` and `b` which add up to 100. How do I set up a reactive declaration such that when `a` changes `b` changes to be `100 - a` and vice versa? When I try something like

```
let total = 100;
$: a = total - b;
$: b = total - a;
```

I get a 'Cyclical dependency detected' error. Is there any way to get this done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that Svelte wants to sort the reactive blocks in the order they depend upon each other: it wants to compute those that are depended upon but have no dependencies first, to avoid unneeded computation... or getting trapped in a loop.

Furthermore, Svelte considers a dependency of a reactive expression any reactive variable that appear in it.

And so, the actual source of your error is that both variables `a` and `b` appears in both reactive expressions.

The solution is to remove from the reactive expressions the unneeded variable, that is the one that is assigned to. This can be done by moving the assignment to a function outside of the reactive block. Unfortunately, it's more verbose...

```html
<script>
    let total = 100;
    let a = 0
    let b = 0
    
    const setA = () => {
        // the assignment to a (or b in the other function) are still
        // reactive, of course, but Svelte won't propagate changes to
        // variable that are assigned their current value, so this
        // will break the loop
        a = total - b
    }
    
    const setB = () => {
        b = total - a
    }
    
    $: setA(total - b);
    $: setB(total - a);
</script>

<pre>
    a: {a}
    b: {b}
</pre>

<label>
    a <input type="number" bind:value={a} />
</label>

<label>
    b <input type="number" bind:value={b} />
</label>
```

**Edit**

As remarked by @avf in the comments, the above code is misleading and not so obvious for the reader of the code. I wrote it like this at the time because I was focused on demonstrating the principles of Svelte reactivity.

In a real world context, I would rather recommend any of the following two forms.

Whenever possible, favour obviousness:

```js
// this function is just normal
const setA = (value) => {
  a = value
}

// this reactive expression makes it obvious and straightforward that 
// its dependencies are total and b, and only those
$: setA(total - b)
```

When obviousness is not an option (for example because the content of the function would be more side effect than mere assignment), I'd rely on the following form that is very idiomatic to Svelte. Unfortunately, it's also very obscure to people who are not familiar to Svelte usually... But I guess that just belongs to those things you've got to learn to be really proficient with the framework.

```js
const recomputeEverythingOrWhatever = () => {
  ...
}

// in Svelte lingo, this is broadly understood as "whenever a, or b, or
// total changes, then recompute everything (or whatever)"
$: a, b, total, recomputeEverythingOrWhatever()
```

This syntax is fine IMO because it is generally familiar and well understood by Svelte developers.

Be careful however with what you put in the recompute function. If it changes the values of the dependencies of the reactive block, the code will compile fine this time, and Svelte would even break update loops at runtime to avoid freezing the JS thread... But you might still end up with code that will be very hard to comprehend or predict.

Comment: I don't know, this feels kinda like an abuse of the reactive system.

It took me a while to understand how this works, since `setA` and `setB` don't take any parameters, and yet you're supplying arguments when you call them in the reactive `$` blocks. You have them there since you want the reactive blocks to trigger, but actually the equation inside the reactive block is arbitrary. This would still work correctly even if you changed the first `$:` to: `$: setA(total + b);`. Or any expression that contains both total and b, really.

Basically, you're using `setA` and `setB` as side effects.

Comment: You're right. I'm not sure I'd call it an abuse but the code in example is poorly written. I was focused on demonstrating what was reactive where. I have edited the answer to add a disclaimer about real world usage.

Comment: That's pretty cool, thanks for the quick edit!

Answer (score 1):

That does not work; Svelte does not allow this and this cycle cannot be resolved either. If you want a variable to be editable, you cannot declare it as reactive (`$: x = ...`). You can either reactively set regular variables with reactive statements/blocks or use events instead (see other answers).

*The following is an explanation why this could not be resolved logically either.*

Treating this like two equations with two unknowns you get this useless simplification:

```
a = total - b
b = total - a
b = total - (total - b)
b = total - total + b
b = b
```

You have to fix at least one of the values, otherwise all possible values are valid here.

---

You can also first normalize the equations:

```
a = total - b => a + b = total => a + b = total
b = total - a => b + a = total => a + b = total
```

As you can see, they are the same, so you actually have two unknowns and only one equation, so this is underspecified.

*(Note that even if this would yield a valid solution, Svelte cannot solve systems of linear equations for you.)*

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need the values to update from programmatic changes, i would drop the reactive statements entirely and work with events instead: When one variable is adjusted by the user, update the other one.

```html
<script>
  const total = 100;
  let a = total;
  let b = 0;
</script>

a: {a} <br>
b: {b}

<label>
  a <input type="number" bind:value={a}
           on:input={() => b = total - a} />
</label>

<label>
  b <input type="number" bind:value={b}
           on:input={() => a = total - b} />
</label>
```